# wasm-bindgen: command not found even though wasm-pack is installed (0.8.1)

Tags: wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack

From this article https://asquera.de/blog/2018-10-01/webassembly-and-wasm-bindgen/ I found we can run `wasm-bindgen target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/qr_wasm.wasm --out-dir ./dist --no-modules --no-typescript` to create wasm and js files without running `wasm-pack build` (it would install wasm-bindgen regardless if I have previously installed one, making it a bit slow) which seems more flexible to me but when I ran `wasm-bindgen xxx` it says: `zsh: command not found: wasm-bindgen`

I googled it but no one seems to have encountered this issue. I also have `cargo install` wasm-bindgen and wasm-bindgen-cli in my project.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure `$HOME/.cargo/bin` is in your `PATH`.

If not:

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.cargo/bin"
```

or edit your `.bashrc` or some other way

Answer (score 3):

I got here from google with the same problem.

My fix was `cargo install wasm-bindgen-cli`, per here: https://docs.rs/crate/wasm-bindgen/0.2.8

Answer (score 0):

I installed `wasm-bindgen` using `cargo install wasm-bindgen-cli` command, however I wasn't able to execute it.

On Arch, I fixed it with `yay -S wasm-bindgen-bin`